# Ajax Submit Form with two variable function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new to javascript and ajax and I wanted to learn a little more. I'm having a little difficulty getting my simple ajax script to work. The purpose of the script is to pass two variables. One variable is known as the current name of a file. The second variable is the new name of the file. The second variable is entered with a textbox.

On clicking the submit button, the script is executed. I know that the function is fine, because I can hard code it and have it work. The problem I seem to be running into is that the second variable is not getting passed correctly.

```
<?php
   $q="Test";
   echo "<form name=\"Form-$q\" method=\"post\" >";
     echo "New File Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"NewNameFor$q\" /><br />";
     echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"ChangeNameButton$q\" value=\"Change\" onclick='ChangeFileName(\"$q\",\"this.form.NewNameFor$q.value\");return false;'>";
   echo "</form>";
?>
```

My code outputs the following:

```
mv /data/Test /data/this.form.NewNameForTest.value
```

So clearly my code is not reading the form input correctly. I'm just not sure what I may have missed.

Comment: Tip: use `echo ''` instead of `echo ""`, so that you won't have to escape the HTML's `"`

Comment: Note: If you do follow @sp00m's advice and change to single quotes, you cannot use variables directly inside the string. You will have to break the string up, like this: `echo '<form name="Form-'. $q .'" method="post" >';`

Comment: I've thought of using single quotes before, but then I find it harder for me to keep track of the layout. I prefer to just escape every quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
onclick='ChangeFileName(\"$q\",\"this.form.NewNameFor$q.value\");
```

You quoted "this.form.NewNameFor$q.value". That means that this **string** will be passed in.

Remove the quotes:

```
onclick='ChangeFileName(\"$q\",this.form.NewNameFor$q.value);
```

Comment: AH, Perfect! I should have thought of that when it was returning the entire phrase.